# Create an object according to a string in C++

Tags: c++, reflection

I have several subclasses of one superclass and want to create an instance of a specific class according to a given string

```
Superclass instantiateSubclass(string s);
```

Instead of having a huge if-cascade I want to work with a config file to accomplish this.

This allows me to change the possible values for string s without recompiling and I hope it leads to a more concise code.

The config file should contain strings like "subclass1", "subclass2", but how do I create the class according to a string then?

Basically I need a mapping from string to class, is this possible in C++? I think other languages offer possibilities like reflection for this problem.

Comment: You want to create object whose type (name of class) is specified by string?

Comment: No way to add sub-classes without recompiling in C++. Somewhere you'll need to create an instance of the concrete class, and the compiler needs to see it. Or are you talking of s.th. else?

Comment: I don't want to add a new subclass. The subclass already exists. I want to instantiate a subclass specified by a given string. I have edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: Ahh I see, then it's all about configuring your class factory. Use a registry then as others mentioned in their answers.

Comment: This is a design pattern called the "Factory method pattern". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Register your classes:

```
struct Base;

struct Derived1 : Base
{
    static Base * create() { return new Derived1; }
};

std::map<std::string, Base * (*)()> registry = { {"derived1", &Derived1::create},
                                                 /* ... */
                                               };
```

To make:

```
Base * create_from_string(std::string const & s)
{
    auto it = registry.find(s);
    return it == registry.end() ? nullptr : (it->second)();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar before. Build an unordered_map of string (type)/function pointer (factory) pairs. Each one points to a static function that creates an instance of the type.

This still requires you to have those little stub factory functions, typically they are one-liners that create that type. Macros can be used to generate the factory methods.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Superclass *(*)()> TypeDirectory;
TypeDirectory types;

#define NAMEFACTORY(name_) static Superclass *Create() { return new name_; }

class Hello : public Superclass
{
   ...

   NAMEFACTORY(Hello)
};

static void RegisterFactoryNames()
{
  types.emplace_back("Hello", &Hello::Create);
  ...
}

static Superclass *MakeInstance(std::string &name)
{
  auto i = types.find(name);
  return i != types.end() ? types->second() : 0;
}
```

Only you would know where the name factory data belongs, I didn't put it "in" anything in my example.

Note: if you're using MSVC 10 or below (2010 or below) then use `types.push_back(TypeDirectory::value_type("Hello", &Hello::Create));` since emplace_back has a completely incorrect implementation in those versions.

Comment: When does RegisterFactoryNames() get run?

Comment: @einpoklum you could check types.empty() and call it from `MakeInstance`. That wouldn't be thread-safe though. If thread safety is needed, then just make sure you call `RegisterFactoryNames` once anytime before `MakeInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you can register any number of classes derived from a base `INTERFACE` and instantiate them with a string returned from `register_class`.

The down side is the keys will be potentially different between platforms and you'll have to know what typeid(CLASS).name() returns for each class to make sure you put the right class key in your config file (it may not be the same as the class name)

Read more on typeid to learn what's happening here

```
   template <class INTERFACE> class factory
    {
    public:
        template <class CLASS> const std::string register_class()
        {
            static const std::string key = typeid(CLASS).name();
            class class_factory : public ifactory
            {
            private:
                virtual std::shared_ptr<INTERFACE> create() const
                {
                    return new CLASS;
                }
            };
            m_factory_map[key] = new class_factory;
            return key;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<INTERFACE> create(const std::string& key) const
        {
            const factory_map::const_iterator ifind = m_factory_map.find(key);
            if(ifind == m_factory_map.end())
                return 0;
            return ifind->second->create();
        }
    private:
        class ifactory
        {
        public:
            virtual ~ifactory() {}
            virtual std::shared_ptr<INTERFACE> create() const = 0;
        };
        typedef std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ifactory> > factory_map;
        factory_map m_factory_map;
    };
```

Use it like this

```
factory<MyInterface> fact;
const std::string key1 = fact.register_class<MyClass1>();
const std::string key2 = fact.register_class<MyClass2>();
const std::string key3 = fact.register_class<MyClass3>();
std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> p1 = fact.create(key1);
std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> p2 = fact.create(key2);
std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> p3 = fact.create(key3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a config file or otherwise, at some point you will need to translate the string into a "new someclass" call [or something along those lines]. This will involve comparing a string, and selecting the correct item to make new of. Either a long chain of if/else if/else if ... or a table, from which you can then make a selection in a switch-statement based on some integer constant you got ouf of a second entry in the table.

The other possibility is of course to completely move the problem to a different level, and implement a shared library per class, and load the relevant library based on it's name, and then have a function of a defined name/ordinal in the shared library that you can call to "make me one of your kind of object".